# Can't open a Visual Studio 2013 project, in design view

Tags: c#, button, visual-studio-2013, design-view

I'm trying to open the design view of "Form1.cs", but I can't see the design view. I obtain that message:

[image]

That message is in Spanish, so I'm trying to translate to English (because I can't install English version...):

"To add components to the class, drag them from the toolbox and use the Properties window to set its properties. To create methods and events for the class, click here to switch to the code view."

The project works perfect, but I can't understand why Visual Studio don't let me see the design view. Quickly, my project show a matrix of a personalized buttons, that are created in execution time.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If your buttons generated on the run time then, it will not be visible in design view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like your form controls (i.e. buttons etc) are getting generated on run time (as you mentioned in the question). Visual Studio shows the static design only in design view any controls generated on runtime will not be shown in design view.

Comment: Ok. But, if I want implement my form controls, in 2 ways? I explain, I want to implement one part of the code dinamic, and another part static, like textboxes, labels, another static buttons... Is this possible?

Comment: In that case static control will be visible in design view. Please try to drag and drop few controls to verify

Comment: But i cant see the whole form, at least to see its size, in order to place the extra static elements with that reference. If you could see the main form in the design view, I could easily place the static elements, but I can't place more elements.